# for-loop in R while creating radar chart

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a radar chart upon reading in data from a CSV file. This data is arranged in such a way that a radar chart is to be plotted after reading in data from a specific column every 5 rows.

I have the code for plotting a radar chart based on reading in (say, in the example below, the first 5 rows) of a particular column. How can I automate it (create a for-loop) such that for every 5 rows of data read in, a radar chart is plotted?

My current code is as such:

```
require(fmsb)
range <- c(0, 2)
id5 <- c(exceldata$excelcolumn[1:5])
id5.df <- data.frame(rbind(max=range[2], min=range[1], id5)
radarchart(id5.df ...)
```

[1:5] is my manual specification of the first 5 rows to be read in prior to plotting the radarchart. How can I change this to a for-loop to plot a radar chart every 5 rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One classic way to do this is to split the seq of rows of your data.frame with a clever index.This should work for you :

```
ll <- split(seq(nrow(exceldata)),cumsum(seq(nrow(exceldata))%%5==1))
lapply(ll,function(x){
        id5 <- c(exceldata$excelcolumn[x])
        id5.df <- data.frame(rbind(max=range[2], min=range[1], id5)
        radarchart(id5.df,...)
}
```

For example , testing this on a reproducible example. I create a data.frame of 20 rows and each 5 rows I create a radarchart.

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 20
dat <- data.frame(
  total=runif(N, 1, 5),
  phys=rnorm(N, 10, 2),
  psycho=sample(c(0.5, NA, 3),N,rep=TRUE),
  social=runif(N, 1, 5),
  env=sample(c(5, 2.5, 4),N,rep=TRUE))

ll <- split(seq(nrow(dat)),cumsum(seq(nrow(dat))%%5==1))
op <- par(mar=c(1, 2, 2, 1),mfrow=c(2, 2))

lapply(ll,
       function(x)radarchart(dat[x,]))
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How about if I have an Excel CSV with data as such: UserID, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3: 100, 1, 1.5, 1.25; 200, 2, 2.5, 2; 300, 1.25, 1, 1; What would be the best way to create 3 separate radar charts (via lapply) with these 3 attributes as the axis of the radar then?